# Disable URL Bar hide on Safari Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

I'm developing a Mobile site template using jQuery Mobile with the iScroll plugin. Basically I want to have a static footer and header. In addition to the iScroll.js I also am including the jquery iScroll script by Kazuhiro Osawa to make it work w/ JQM. In his script you can offset the height of the URL bar in Safari Mobile. The problem is after the page loads Safari's URL bar hides and creates a bunch of padding at the bottom. In the script I can offset this, but this will kill Android UX. 
Does anyone have any ideas or a solution for this? Ideally, I would like to detect the device window size and perform something like this: [device window size - (Header Height + Footer Height)] = Scrollable window size. That way I don't have to hard code a work around that is device specific. Thanks.

```
<div data-role="page" data-iscroll="enable" id="home">

      <div data-role="header">
    <h1>INDEX PAGE</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
    <div data-iscroll="scroller">
          <ol data-role="listview">
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" style="height:45px">
    I'm a Footer
      </div>

    </div>
```

And here is the script to tie in iScroll w/ jQuery Mobile

```
(function($) {
$(function() {

var SafariWindowHeightFix = 34; // Here is where you can offset the height of the URL bar:

function fixed(elm) {
    if (elm.data("iscroll-plugin")) {
        return;
    }

    // XXX: fix crumbled css in transition changePage 
    // for jquery mobile 1.0a3 in jquery.mobile.navigation.js changePage
    //  in loadComplete in removeContainerClasses in .removeClass(pageContainerClasses.join(" "));
    elm.css({
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });

    var barHeight = 0;
    var $header = elm.find('[data-role="header"]');
    if ($header.length) {
        $header.css({
            "z-index": 1000,
            padding: 0,
            width: "100%"
        });
        barHeight += $header.height();
    }

    var $footer = elm.find('[data-role="footer"]');
    if ($footer.length) {
        $footer.css({
            "z-index": 1000,
            padding: 0,
            width: "100%"
        });
        barHeight += $footer.height();
    }

    var $wrapper = elm.find('[data-role="content"]');
    if ($wrapper.length) {
        $wrapper.css({
            "z-index": 1
        });
        $wrapper.height($(window).height() - barHeight - SafariWindowHeightFix);
        $wrapper.bind('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    }

    var scroller = elm.find('[data-iscroll="scroller"]').get(0);
    if (scroller) {
        var iscroll = new iScroll(scroller, {desktopCompatibility:true});
        elm.data("iscroll-plugin", iscroll);
    }
}
$('[data-role="page"][data-iscroll="enable"]').live("pageshow", function() {
    fixed($(this));
});
if ($.mobile.activePage.data("iscroll") == "enable") {
    fixed($.mobile.activePage);
}

});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you don't need iScroll anymore to have fixed headers and footers in Mobile Safari (you never really needed it for Android) because position:fixed and -webkit-overflow-scrolling were added in iOS5. Mobile Tuts did a really nice writeup explaining the changes in detail here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-content-scrolling/

Comment: Thanks, after reading that article it looks like the major browsers are moving towards a more light-weight css solution and trying to deviate from the js solutions out there like iScroll and Scrollview.